# How to run Memgraph database without any disk persistence

Tags: memgraphdb

How to run Memgraph database with the database in memory only with no snapshots to disk and no write-ahead logging, no disk persistence. I am happy to loose all data is the database is stopped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as of yet an un-tested answer, but looking at the configuration file in /etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf there are parameters related to durability of storage, I would set this to turn off durability.

```
--durability-enabled=false
```

There are other configuration parameters after this one also related to persistence, I would set them as follows, just to be sure. Although I assume the above configuration set to false would turn off all durability.

```
--db-recover-on-startup=false
--snapshot-cycle-sec=-1
--snapshot-on-exit=false
--snapshot-max-retained=3
--synchronous-commit=false
```